# How to create velocity template for existing html?

Tags: java, html, velocity

I am new to Apache Velocity. I want to know how to update the existing html template to convert it into a Velocity template. And when this template is ready it is inserted into the database and at runtime we need to call Java objects to replace the variables.

Lets say I have a jsp file like this:

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 0px auto; width: 36%; margin-top:18px;">
    <div class="btnAdd">
        <input type="button" id="savePopUp"
            class="save_drafts" class="save_drafts" value="Add >>"
        onclick="transferSelectedItems($('#lbFieldSelectInput'),$('#ldFieldSelectOutput'));">
    </div>
    <div class="btnAdd">
        <input type="button" id="savePopUp"
            class="save_drafts" class="save_drafts" value="Add All >>"
        onclick="transferAllItems($('#lbFieldSelectInput'),$('#ldFieldSelectOutput'));">
    </div>
    <div class="btnRemove">
        <input type="button" id="resetPopUp" class="save_drafts"
            value="<< Remove"
        onclick="transferSelectedItems($('#ldFieldSelectOutput'),$('#lbFieldSelectInput'));">
    </div>
    <div class="btnRemove">
        <input type="button" id="resetPopUp" class="save_drafts"
            value="<< Remove All"
        onclick="transferAllItems($('#ldFieldSelectOutput'),$('#lbFieldSelectInput'));">
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I insert the variables to convert this to a Velocity template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert this for velocity template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916877/how-to-convert-this-for-velocity-template)

Answer (score 0):

In reference with my [previous reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916877/how-to-convert-this-for-velocity-template/34702189#34702189), to convert this into a Velocity template, you must have an idea what you EXACTLY want to do. That's step 1.

Then you have to decide what particular part you want to render with velocity. In your code, I guess the best part would be the values. You may support the *values*
 you are rendering to a local database (or file), retrieve them and put values in the context. Example:-

```
String value1, value2, value3;
//Read the values as per required.
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("value1", value1);
//...
```

In your velocity template file:

```
    <div class="btnRemove">
        <input type="button" id="resetPopUp" class="save_drafts"
            value="$value1"
        onclick="transferSelectedItems($('#ldFieldSelectOutput'),$('#lbFieldSelectInput'));">
    </div>
```

For further info and guidance, please refer to the Velocity Docs.